# how to use superagent-proxy?

Tags: node.js, superagent

I find it hard to use [superagent-proxy](https://github.com/TooTallNate/superagent-proxy), just with the simple code:

```
const superagent = require('superagent')
require('superagent-proxy')(superagent)

let proxy = 'http://221.237.122.22:8118' // 设置代理

superagent
  .get('http://sf.gg')
  .proxy(proxy)
  .timeout(3600*1000)
  .end((err, res) => {
    console.log(res)
    console.log(res.status, res.headers);
    console.log(res.body);
  })
```

but when run, it cannot get an reply, why?

Comment: Is there an error code？

Comment: no error, and no reply..

Answer (score 2):

you should:

```
const superagent = require('superagent')
require('superagent-proxy')(superagent)

let proxy = 'http://221.237.122.22:8118' // 设置代理

superagent
  .get('http://sf.gg')
  .proxy(proxy)
  .timeout(3600*1000)
  .end((err, res) => {
    if(err) {
       console.error(err);
       return;
    }
    console.log(res)
    console.log(res.status, res.headers);
    console.log(res.body);
  })
```

then, you will get error such as

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 221.237.122.22:8118
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '221.237.122.22',
  port: 8118,
  response: undefined }
```

Comment: instead of  behaving  that way, I still got nothing

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct, proxy URL is not - if its exactly
'http://221.237.122.22:8118'
it means proxy do not require any login, anybody can use it with just URL, its not the case for most of the proxies, normally proxy URL is like 'http://username:password@IPADDRESS_OR_HOST:PORT'